# Change spacing between elements in \newfloat listof

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I have created a new float type with the following in my preamble:

```
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{myfloat}{thpb}{myfloat}[chapter]
\floatname{myfloat}{\bf My Float}
```

Then I use the following to create a list at the beginning of my document of all of these new floats:

```
\listof{myfloat}{My Floats}
```

I'd like to change the spacing between the elements in the list of myfloat's such that it matches the spacing in my listoffigures and listoftables.

I'm using a class based on the book class (more specifically: http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/physics/thesis/buthesis.cls).

Comment: Do not use `\bf ...` but `\textbf{My Float}`. See [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/2975) or [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/) for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the same format for the new list of floats, it's necessary to redefine two commands: `\listof` from `float.sty` (I assumed that you are using this package to build your new float type) and `\@chapter` from `book.cls` (the standard class on top of which `buthesis.cls` is build). The first redefinition only changes `\parskip` from `0pt` (default value used for the new lists created with float) to `0.2in` (which is the value used for `buthesis.cls`). The second redefinition simply adds a vertical space of `10pt` at the beginning of each chapter in the new list.

The relevant code that has to be added to the preamble (after the `float` package has been loaded) is the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
    \float@listhead{#2}%
  \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{0.2in}% default: 0pt
    \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
  \endgroup}}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{myfloat}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%adds space to the new list
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother
```