# Why are \listof{}{} and \listoffigures styled differently?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, formatting

I'm writing my thesis and I have certain code-snippets to show. I'm using the the `listings` package embedded in a custom `float` environment to display them.

To list them in an index at the beginning of my document - similar to `\listoffigures` - I use:

```
\listof{code}{List of Code}
```

This (technically) works as desired but looks completely different to my list of figures. See screenshot below (List of Figures on the left, List of Code on the right).

[image: lof vs loc]

Why, and how to fix this? Or how to modify the `\listof{}{}` layout to look similar to the one of `\listoffigures`?

I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14867/14076) workaround which redefines the layout but it's not working as desired (still looks different) and is throwing more errors than I could post here.

**Update 1**: After some hours of trying to figure out of what wrong with my document (It's really bloated already.) I'll try to explain this with a minimal working example. Notice the screenshots below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{float}
  \newfloat{algo}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
  \setlength{\parskip}{3mm}     % !
  \setlength{\parindent}{3mm}   % !
  \frenchspacing
  \sloppy

 \begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \listof{algo}{List of Algorithms}

  \chapter{foo}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{A figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{An algorithm}
   \end{algo}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Another figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{Another algorithm}
   \end{algo}

  \chapter{bar}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Yet another figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{Yet another algorithm}
   \end{algo}

 \end{document}
```

[image: parskip]

Parskip and parindent seem to play an important role, still I dont get a result as mentioned in [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s answer (with the spacing between chapters) ...

**Update 2**: Okay, now I found the reason why it's not working. It's the `hyperref` package. Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{float}
  \newfloat{algo}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
%  \setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
%  \setlength{\parindent}{3mm}
  \frenchspacing
  \sloppy
% \usepackage{hyperref}                    % !!!
%  \hypersetup{pdftitle={Bachelorthesis}}  % !!!
%  \hypersetup{colorlinks=false}           % !!!
%  \hypersetup{plainpages=false}           % !!!
%  \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}          % !!!
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
 \makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}%
  {\addtocontents{lof}}%
  {\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
   \addtocontents{lof}}%
  {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
 \makeatother


 \begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \listof{algo}{List of Algorithms}

  \chapter{foo}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{A figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{An algorithm}
   \end{algo}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Another figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{Another algorithm}
   \end{algo}

  \chapter{bar}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Yet another figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{Yet another algorithm}
   \end{algo}

 \end{document}
```

Uncommenting the hyperref package and settings messed up the layout of the custom `\listof`.

So to break down this issue:

1. How to adjust `\parskip` and `\parindent` without messing up the lists?
2. How to avoid `hyperref` package messing around with the layout?

**Update 3**: Closed this question:

1. *How to adjust `\parskip` and `\parindent` without messing up the lists?* I asked a follow-up question here: [How to avoid `\parskip` being applied to `\listoffigures` etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58619/how-to-avoid-parskip-being-applied-to-listoffigures-etc)
2. *How to avoid `hyperref` package messing around with the layout?* Solved: Simply loading hyperref at the end of all packages and **after** `\makeatother`.

Thanks to [Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/frank-mittelbach)'s workaround which helped me to solve the layout issue till this point.

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}`, added MWE now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a fault of the `float`package you might say. It defines the `\listof`command as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
    \float@listhead{#2}%
    \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
      \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
    \endgroup}}
```

This means that it a) fixes the `\parskip` to zero (which would be usually ok but still somewhat questionable) and b) gives each "listof" line a hard-wired meaning, by defining `\l@<type>`. The values used are the default values for `\@lfigure` in the article class. However, if the class you use has different values (and it looks like it has) they are obviously not picked up.

Resolution: provide your own copy of `\listof` looking like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \expandafter\let\csname l@#1\endcsname \l@figure  % <- use layout of figure
    \float@listhead{#2}%
    \begingroup
      \setlength\parskip{0pt plus 1pt}%               % <- or drop this line completely
      \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
    \endgroup}}
\makeatother
```

This will make the formatting of the "list-of" lines the same as those for figures in the "List of Figures" listing and it will reset the spacing between paragrpahs (and each line here is a paragraph) to the default used by the article/report class. The alternative would be to take that setting completely out.

However, this is not quite enough in case `report` or `book` class is used. As mentioned in the answer by @lockstep the `\chapter` command also adds vertical space material to such listings. So in addition the `\@chapter` command needs to be patched to include this extra space. So you need something like

```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\@chapter}%
     {\addtocontents{lof}}%
     {\addtocontents{alg}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%  % <-- "alg" is the extension you use
      \addtocontents{lof}}%
     {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
   \makeatother
```

where you have to replace "alg" with whatever the file extension is that you use

Comment: Understanding the problem but not exactly your provided code. And it's not working. My document class is `report`.

Comment: By not working you mean it crashes (hope not) or that it doesn't give the same results? I have updated the answer as with report class there \parskip spacing will be a problem as well as the extra space added by \chapter. Hope those are now all differences.

Comment: The last updated code snippet doesnt not throw any errors, even tho I don't see any changes in layout. I added a MWE to my question now.

Comment: well, did you change "alg" to "loa"? And did you drop or change the setting of the \parskip line? As you use 3mm you have to use that there too (or remove the line completely). When I run your MWE with my code added it works as expected.

Comment: it's working with the MWE now, but not with my main document. it's too complex to figure out whats wrong i guess :(

Comment: depends. One would need to analyse which additional setting are applied or what other changes your extra package do to \listoffigures.  Add \usepackage{trace} ... \traceon\listoffigures\traceoff in your real document and send me the log per email (frank.mittelbach @ latex-project.org)

Answer (score 3):

The workaround you tried is for the `book` class which features a different defintion of `\chapter`. For `report`, the following works for me (i.e., yields identical formatting for the List of Figures and the newly defined List of Algorithms):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{algo}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\listof{algo}{List of Algorithms}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algo}
(algo)
\caption{An algorithm}
\end{algo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algo}
(algo)
\caption{Another algorithm}
\end{algo}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{Yet another figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algo}
(algo)
\caption{Yet another algorithm}
\end{algo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Note: The screenshot you provided does *not* look like the default LoF spacing for the `report` class (there's additional spacing between entries located in the same chapter). You should provide a MWE showing the relevant packages and/or individual customizations.

Comment: my guess is that this is the parskip spacing and the fact that report has flushbottom

Comment: @FrankMittelbach By default (i.e., with `oneside` and without `twocolumn`), `report` features `\raggedbottom`.