# How to avoid \parskip being applied to \listoffigures etc.?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, paragraphs, parskip

Follow-up question of [Why are `\listof{}{}` and `\listoffigures` styled differently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58469/why-are-listof-and-listoffigures-styled-differently)...

With the issue mentioned above I finally managed to design my `\listof{}{}` and `\listoffigures` as desired but one issue remains unsolved: How to avoid global settings for my document like `\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}` being applied to list of figures, list of tables, etc.?

MWE: Uncommenting `\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}` affects the `\listoffigures` but not the `\listof{algo}{List of Algorithms}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{float}
  \newfloat{algo}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]
%  \setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
%  \setlength{\parindent}{3mm}
  \frenchspacing
  \sloppy
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
 \makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\@chapter}%
  {\addtocontents{lof}}%
  {\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
   \addtocontents{lof}}%
  {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
 \makeatother


 \begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \listof{algo}{List of Algorithms}

  \chapter{foo}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{A figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{An algorithm}
   \end{algo}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Another figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{Another algorithm}
   \end{algo}

  \chapter{bar}
   \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{1cm}{1cm}
    \caption{Yet another figure}
   \end{figure}
   \begin{algo}
    (algo)
    \caption{Yet another algorithm}
   \end{algo}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting `\parskip` to a rigid value, to begin with and probably using the `parskip` package is better. Just enclose the lists in a group where you set the parskip to zero.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{algo}{tbp}{loa}[chapter]

\usepackage{parskip}

\frenchspacing

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lof}}
  {\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}\addtocontents{lof}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus .1pt}
\listoffigures
\listof{algo}{List of Algorithms}
\endgroup

\chapter{foo}
...
```

I would never use a nonzero parskip *and* a nonzero indentation (to be honest I'd *never* use a nonzero parskip). Also declaring `\sloppy` for the whole document is asking for poor typography even when TeX could do better.