# How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

How to avoid using `\sloppy` document-wide to fix overfull `\hbox` problems?

[image: overfull \hbox]

This is my minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[a4paper,inner=25mm,outer=25mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
  Have a look at this URL ignoring the page margin within the text flow \textit{example.com/donc\_oe/longurl} lorem ipsum.\par
  The very strange plugin Java-JDT (\textit{en. Java Development Toolkit}) "`Plugin-Entwicklungsumgebung"' -- what's wrong with this german word?\par
  \lipsum[2]
 \end{document}
```

With `\sloppy` it looks better.

[image]

But [I got told](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58621/14076) it's (obviously) better to avoid using it document-wide. What else can I do?

Comment: For the first one, you could use `\url` from the `url` package.

Comment: You should be saying `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`; so input the offending long word as `Plugin"-Entwicklungsumgebung`, using the `"-` shorthand: a hyphen allowing hyphenation in the rest of the word.

Comment: Nobody suggests microtype? That won't help you there but it is always good to consider when typing text

Comment: The word "Plugin-Entwicklungsumgebung" should be written as `Plugin"=Entwicklungsumgebung`

Comment: Contrarian question: how do I enable `\sloppy` throughout the whole document?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- When typesetting URLs, use the [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url), since it provides adequate line-breaking support. If needed, you can change the typeface it uses in its display (default is `\ttfamily`).
- Words not covered by default hyphenation (or that provided by [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) can be incorporated in an ad-hoc way using `\-` or globally using `\hypenation{<this-is-an-awk-ward-ly-long-word>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=25mm,outer=25mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
Have a look at this URL ignoring the page margin within the text flow \url{example.com/donc_oe/longurl} lorem ipsum.\par
The very strange plugin Java-JDT (\textit{en. Java Development Toolkit}) "`Plugin-Ent\-wick\-lungs\-umge\-bung"' -- what's wrong with this German word?\par
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you write Plugin"=Entwicklungsumgebung the second problem should go away by itself. It is always good to write "= instead of - on long German words with `-`.

Answer (score 34):

Also, you might want to set

```
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2pt}
```

or something similar.  Explanation: if TeX can't typeset a paragraph without bad boxes, and `\emergencystretch` is nonzero, it tries once again, but this time increasing the stretchability of the space by the value of this parameter.

Comment: Does it matter where you put this command?

Comment: I'd put in in the preamble, or within a group - depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 30):

another tactic, after fixing urls as described by Werner, is to wrap the environment `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` around just those paragraphs that still have problems.

this does much the same thing as setting `\emergencystretch`, with preset values.

Comment: `\begin{sloppypar}` uses `\sloppy` locally and is documented here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50850/1340—that answer recommends considering `emergencystretch` over `sloppy`, as the former does not allow small overfull hboxes.