# Line goes out of paragraph, when I give hyperlink

Tags: line-breaking, urls

I'm trying to hyperlink `\url{http://brollace.blogspot.de/2012/03/havok-tutorial-content-tools-part-1.html.}`, but when I compile it, the line goes out of the boundary of paragraph.
Can anybody knows why?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` or `latex`? The DVI format doesn't break hyperlinks.

Comment: This is rather a style suggestion, but you could use a footnote for the actual URL, leaving only title in the text. See if your document's format would allow and benefit from that.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have a  . at the end of the url \url{http://brollace.blogspot.de/2012/03/havok-tutorial-content-tools-part-1.html.} ?

**EDIT_**
Sometimes, when LaTeX cannot break lines nicely, it leaves them unadjusted. You can control that behavior putting \sloppy at the beginnig of your document

see 
[How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59122/how-to-avoid-using-sloppy-document-wide-to-fix-overfull-hbox-problems)
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146606/wrap-url-ignores-margin-in-bibtex-using-pdflatex

Comment: it was typo,  but after removing it also, it doesn't work again.

Comment: The link on the edit has ways to get around using \sloppy ..

Answer (score 1):

Since the URL is actually longer than a line, it needs to break if you want it to fit within the paragraph. In your case the only conceivable break points are the backslashes, the dot or the hyphens. By default, the `url` package (loaded by you or by the `hyperref` package or some other package) does not allow breaking at hyphens (see the documentation for an explanation). To tell the `url` package it may break a URL at hyphens you load it with the `hyphens` option:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
I'm trying to hyperlink
\url{http://brollace.blogspot.de/2012/03/havok-tutorial-content-tools-part-1.html},
but when I compile it, the line goes out of the boundary of paragraph.
Can anybody knows why?
\end{document}
```

If `url` was being loaded automatically by some other package like `hyperref`, load it yourself with this option before that package.