# underfull \hbox badness 8094

Tags: abstract

In my abstract I am getting the badness 8094 and in some other paragraphs 3260, 1688 and 4927.

Could anyone please tell me what do they mean and how could I resolve them?

Thanks

Comment: it means that tex is having to over-stretch the white space in order to justify the lines in that paragraph, Do you have large unbreakable "words" such as technical or foreign terms? You could try `\sloppy` which tells tex to allow more stretch or give tex other help to find good linebreaks

Comment: this might be useful: [How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?]
(https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59122)

Comment: I have this these warnings coming up on abstract where all text comes on one line. My abstract text consists of around 250 words. I do not know after how many words it should split into new line.