# \mbox overflowing the line

Tags: errors, formatting

I'm trying to avoid a line break in a middle of a method name as it can be seen here:
[image]

I want PredRNN++ to remain intact.
I tried using

```
\mbox{PredRNN++}
```

but then the name gets pushed out into the right margin as this:
[image]

1. Why does this happen?
2. How could I achieve the result of "PredRNN++" not being line-breaked?

Comment: (untested) Try `Pred~RNN++`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `Pred~RNN++` results in a space between "Pred" and "RNN++", also it still overflows the line.

Comment: rewrite the sentence suitably?

Comment: Try the `sloppypar` recommendation given in an answer to this question: [How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59122).  (Potential duplicate.)

Comment: I am leaning more towards rewritting the sentence, but I was curious why was this happening.

Comment: tex does a least cost algorithm to optimise line breaking over a paragraph but no solution was found without exceeding the user settable constraints on how much white space can stretch. You provided no example code but there are typically few potential break points in the first line of a paragraph. If you use `\sloppy` then more white space stretching is allowed.

Comment: What outcome are you hoping for with no line break?  If TeX pushes PredRNN++ to the next line, it will want to spread the rest of the first line to take out that extra space.  Would that be acceptable?  If not, what would be?

Comment: @Teepeemm yes, I was expecting PredRNN++ to be pushed to the next line and the first line to take out the extra space.

Comment: But I guess @DavidCarlisle explains why this is happening.

Comment: `\sloppy` probably does what you wanted but hard to be sure as you provided no example (it is almost always best to include a test document with the question)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the linebreaking problem, insert a tie between the compounds, i.e. `Pred~RNN++`.  If that results in an overfull box (aka the line going into the margin), you have two options.

[image]

1. Rewrite the sentence.  Usually is suffices to transpose some words.  In the case of the picture above swapping `Pred~RNN++` and `nunc` would fix it.
2. Wrap the whole paragraph in a `sloppypar` environment.

   ```latex
   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{sloppypar}
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur massa turpis,
   semper quis fringilla ut, viverra nec risus. Pellentesque habitant morbi
   tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec Pred~RNN++ nunc
   lorem, sollicitudin vel sodales eget, vehicula nec mi. Proin ullamcorper rutrum
   nibh, at porttitor nunc euismod et. Donec faucibus nisi faucibus ipsum porttitor
   pharetra. Sed elementum, lectus nec congue imperdiet, ipsum leo viverra nisi, sit
   amet commodo odio odio id nisl. Fusce sagittis lobortis nisi sed consectetur. Nam
   egestas, sem ut fermentum convallis, ipsum tellus venenatis augue, eget
   condimentum risus quam id erat. Sed metus dui, sollicitudin pharetra pellentesque
   sed, placerat eget augue. Mauris sodales pretium tortor vitae rutrum. Proin quam
   sem, lobortis tincidunt pretium vitae, feugiat eu lacus.
   \end{sloppypar}
   \end{document}
   ```

   But this might lead to excessive spacing between words.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can stop hyphenation altogether by putting

```
\hyphenpenalty 10000
```

in the preamble. That is probably not the desired effect. You can stop the hyphenation of acronyms (such as PredRNN++) by putting

```
\uchyph=0
```

in the preamble. However, when I tried it, the acronym was not split, but rather extended into the right margins, and I am not sure if this is the desired effect.

Source: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wdnohyph

Comment: Disabling hyphenation for an entire document is extreme, and likely to result in even more overfull lines.  Avoiding the latter when hyphenation is disabled is often accomplished using ragged right, but that's not an appropriate "solution" here.