# \addtolength is causing registered symbol to go beyond the margin

Tags: symbols, margins

I am having a little but painful problem that is the registered trademark symbol in my thesis is going beyond the right margin (see the figure). I have noticed that if I do not use `\addtolength` command then the problem is solved. However, I am searching a solution using which the problem could be solved without removing the `\addtolength`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\hoffset-7mm
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb, amsthm}


%======================================================
\addtolength{\textwidth}{18mm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{10mm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}

\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}
    \item The \textbf{Preprocessing time} means the average time taken, in seconds, by MATLAB{$^{\mbox{\small\textregistered}}$} to generate the constraint matrix and other parameters required to solve the model by the CPLEX{$^{\mbox{\small\textregistered}}$} solver. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of `MATLAB{$^{\mbox{\small\textregistered}}$}` you probably want `MATLAB\textsuperscript{\textregistered}`.

Comment: @campa it is true that same thing can be done as you suggested but the problem of crossing of margins still persists.

Comment: LaTeX estimated that crossing borders for small amount is less disturbing than push whole word in new line.

Comment: The first line of the paragraph is set as tight as possible, and the line is just too long.  It has nothing to do with the "registered" sign.  @Zarko's explanation is correct.  If you really want to reset the paragraph so that "MATLAB" goes on the next line, you can use the `sloppypar` environment: [How to avoid using \sloppy document-wide to fix overfull \hbox problems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59122)

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for your suggestion the sloppypar environment really solved my problem.